# How to attach large files (stored online) to an email without copying the entire file to memory

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, inputstream, google-cloud-storage, email-attachments

How do I send an email using the Java Mail API that contains large attachments (~25 MB)? The attachments are files stored online with our cloud storage provider (Google Cloud Storage). The API for the service returns an `InputStream` object or a `ReadableByteChannel` object for each file.

I can't use `ByteArrayDataSource` to create a `MimeBodyPart` because it creates a copy of the entire file that resides in the memory, and we get a `OutOfMemoryError`.

If its a physical file, we can create a `FileDataSource` object and attach to the email. But can we do it with an `InputStream` object?

I can't increase the heap size because increasing it to 25MB seems like a very bad idea. If you have any other ideas too, please let me know. We're working on the Google App Engine platform.

Comment: 25MB is causing you to run out of heap space?  That is a tiny heap.  Note also that some recipients will not be able to get 25MB attachments (seems to be especially true, even today, in large corporate environments).

Comment: The emails are sent to users using popular services like Gmail, Live or Yahoo and all of them support attachments that are 20-25 MB. Our software runs in a PaaS (Google App Engine).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [javax.activation.URLDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/URLDataSource.html#URLDataSource(java.net.URL)) or the [javax.activation.FileDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/FileDataSource.html#FileDataSource(java.lang.String)) instead.  Otherwise, you can create your own [DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/DataSource.html) adapter class to directly return the given InputStream.

```
public class InputStreamDataSource implements javax.activation.DataSource {

    private final InputStream in;

    public InputStreamDataSource(final InputStream in) {
        if (in == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return in;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "some name";
    }
}
```

Comment: The online files are private, but let me see if I can get a temporary URL and load it as a source. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on my way to home now. I'll try to use that too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a time to copy the InputStream to a physical file and use the FileDataSource object to attach it. But better still would be not to send as an attachment, just send the link to the object in cloud storage.  If you need to control access to the item in cloud storage, send a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs).

Comment: Our client (unfortunately) insists he wants the emails to look "normal" and not have download links in them. I've heard Google App Engine doesn't allow us to create files. But I haven't tried it yet. Let me try that. Thanks.